# Shape does not appear on ImageButton using selector

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I am trying to give click effect in imagebutton through selector and I have used shape . But problem is when i use selector with android:Background only small part on top left become orange .

selector xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/orange"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

and my image xml

```
<ImageButton
   style="@style/icon"
   android:background="@drawable/icon_selector"
   android:src="@drawable/fear_96"
   android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

But when i change selector from background to src then nothing happen

```
<ImageButton
  style="@style/icon"
   android:background="@drawable/fear_96"
   android:src="@drawable/icon_selector"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

please help how can i give click effect using selector ?

Comment: can you explain about what effect you want to achieve?

Comment: when image icon is pressed or touch orange color should appear on icon so that user can feel that image is button which is pressed

Comment: so the orange color will cover the image when you touch or press right?

Comment: Yes i want to cover image with orange color . and it will be good if orange colour is light so that i can see the icon as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code change `android:color` to`android:drawable` and you can use color as drawable see image.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/orange"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fear_96" />
</selector>
```

set as Background

```
<ImageButton
   style="@style/icon"
   android:background="@drawable/icon_selector"
   android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: @FaisalAhmed if still have some issue comment here.

Comment: @FaisalAhmed great happy coding and stay helping your brothers.

Comment: please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290196/string-tag-in-xml-is-creating-some-issue-in-api-above-16

Answer (score 0):

In `icon_selector` xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/orange"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fear_96" />
</selector>
```

And in your ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
   style="@style/icon"
   android:background="@drawable/icon_selector"
   android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: after adding your xml file it gives FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class ImageButton

Comment: @FaisalAhmed can you remove the `style="@style/icon"` and run again