# String tag in xml is creating some issue in api above 16

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making an app that is in two language English and urdu . I have string file for english and i have string name as When_undressing_ar

```
  <string name="When_undressing_ar">بِسْمِ اللهِ</string>
```

and have seperate urdu string xml for urdu language and it has string tag as

```
<string name="لباس_اتارتے_وقت_کیا_پڑھیں_ar">بِسْمِ اللهِ</string>
```

and geting those values from string by calling

```
private static String getDuwaElement(String nameame, Context context) {
int duwaId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getPackageName());

return context.getString(duwaId);
}
```

where name is "When_undressing_ar" when language is set to english. And name is "لباس_اتارتے_وقت_کیا_پڑھیں_ar" when language is set to urdu

this all works fine and give me all the resource in both the language ,

However when i tried this app on api 22 it give exception that resources is not found . This works good till api 16. But gives exception when running on api higher then 16 . Please help what is causing this issue, It gives resource not found exceptions

Comment: you shouldn't translate the key of the string i.e name="When_undressing_ar". For example textview.setText(R.string.when_undressing_ar); will get the en resource in case language is set to en and urdu resource if device language is urdu

Comment: I know that , I have used such logic that it should be in urdu . My Question is why this is giving me problem in api higher then 16

Comment: what is the name of the folder for your urdu values?

Comment: also post the complete stack trace with your question

Comment: shouldn't it be something like values-ur?

Comment: you have to create two seprate xml file one with english and one with urdu with String-ar name and then set locale to urdu system will get the urdu automatically and set translatable true.

Comment: yes it is , sorry i gave u the file name. Its working fine on api level16 . when language is changed

Comment: post the complete error log with your question

Comment: yes i did all and it works good on api level 16 but gives exception on above level . See My question i have mentioned that i have two file

Comment: try the demo answered below

Comment: Offtopic, but for the record: telling you the truth is **not** being rude. It is not my fault if you have wrong expectations towards this community. This one is a perfectly fine question; the other one was not. I took the time to explain to you why that is; whereas other people just downvote and close-requested your question. If you find that "rude"; well, I can live with that. It is not my responsibility to uphold your misconceptions regarding "what to ask" here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Full working Demo**

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    TextView textView;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String[] SuppertedLangCodes = {"en", "ur"};
    String key = "lang";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodName);
        textView.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.txt_name));
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (preferences.getString("lang", "").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") || preferences.getString("lang", "").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(SuppertedLangCodes[0])) {

                    applyLanguage(context, SuppertedLangCodes[1]);
                    preferences.edit().putString(key, SuppertedLangCodes[1]).apply();
                } else {

                    applyLanguage(context, SuppertedLangCodes[0]);
                    preferences.edit().putString(key, SuppertedLangCodes[0]).apply();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void applyLanguage(Context context, String language) {
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        // Since API level 17 or below cause issues with RTL, lets keep them LTR
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            config.locale = new Locale("en");
        } else {
            config.locale = new Locale(language);
        }
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        recreate();
    }
}
```

**activity_main:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foodName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Strings.xml  normal**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Gallery Test</string>
    <string name="txt_title_photo_gallery">Photo Gallery</string>
    <string name="txt_name">what to pray while undressing</string>

</resources>
```

**Strings.xml  from ur folder**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">

        <!--<string name="txt_name" translatable="false">pk.wiseapps.texter.sms.ps.GSM_SMS</string>-->
        <string name="txt_name">لباس_اتارتے_وقت_کیا_پڑھیں</string>

    </resources>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am giving name in urdu in this place "txt_name". i think i should change my logic and give  name in english in both urdu and english