# Why my app is not turning to arabic language automatically?

Tags: android, locale

In my application I have implemented arabic language along with other languages. When I change to arabic language in my device settings my app is not turning to arabic language, but for other languages, it is automatically turning. I dont know what I am missing the code implementation.

Comment: Can you please share your code with a [mcve]?

Comment: is your app rtl supported?

Comment: languages.add(new Language("لعربية","ar_IL"));
In resource folder I haved added the values of strings as xml

Comment: yes rtl is supported in my app

Comment: @MahalakshmiSaravanan look here my earliror answer comment if you have any issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290196/string-tag-in-xml-is-creating-some-issue-in-api-above-16/39291563#39291563

Comment: yes the issue is when I start my app for the first time after changing the language in device my strings in the app are not getting changed to arabic but the rtl method is applied, but when I change the language inside my app the strings are getting changed, where should I make change for the first time the string to get changed?

Comment: Does the device language change take effect if your force close and reopen the app?